# Remove duplicates when joining tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a news table as follows

News:

```
| id  | title                       | description
| 1   | Breaking news               | bla bla bla
| 2   | Heavy snowfall in london    | bla bla bla
```

a Type table as follows:

```
| id  | type_name   | type_code
| 1   | weather     | 0567
| 2   | city        | 0653
```

and a NewsType table as follows

```
|id | news_id | type_id | created_by |
| 1 | 2       | 1       | "John"     |
| 2 | 2       | 2       | "Alex"     |
```

As you can see from the NewsType table that a single news can fall into two or more types.

I need to display news corresponding to types. A user might say give me all the news about cities and weather. To display this I am doing something like:

```
      select distinct n.* , nt.created_at
      from news n, newstype nt, type t where
      n.id = nt.news_id and
      t.id = nt.type_id 
      order by nt.created_at
      limit 25
```

The problem is this query returns the same news twice (I think it's because of the inner join I am doing). What should I change in the query so that if a news is classified as two types, and the user has requested to view the same two types of news, I get only single news item? instead of two!

Comment: `select distinct n.*` shouldn't select the same news twice...

Comment: The query as written will not return any duplicate rows because of `distinct`.  Perhaps you should show the actual query you are using.

Comment: You are right guys....I have edited my question to show the real query That I am using!

Comment: In postgresql, created_at column is implicit. its added to every relation! It's a `DateTime` field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple solution:

```
select * from news where news_id in (
select news_id 
from NewsType 
where type_id in (the types you want)
)
```

most people would say that you should add a DISTINCT on the news_id on the inner query. You can try that, but Im quite sure it will decrese performance.

Over all, if you think this solution doesnt perform well, you can make the inner query a CTE, which usually behaves better:

```
with my_CTE as(
    select news_id 
    from NewsType 
    where type_id in (the types you want)
)
select * 
from news 
where news_id in (select news_id  from my_CTE)
```

Comment: I think `DISTINCT` would increase performance in some cases.  It depends on the relative complexity and size of the inner and outer queries.

Comment: Thanks Diego. A very simple solution indeed!

Comment: There won't be any performance difference between the version with the sub-query and the CTE.

Comment: dan and horse, Ive come accross both situations where the query behaved badly with DISTICNT and where implementing  CTE instead of an inner query improved performance. It depends on several factor, like size of both data sets and indexes for exmaple. Thats why I always advise to test both situations

Comment: Diego if you dont mind....how can I order the results by created_at field in NewsType table?

Comment: you can add ORDER BY my_cte.created_at in the end and add the created_at field to the select inside the CTE so  select news_id, created_at....

Comment: I think it will generate `subquery has too many columns` error. cause the outer query is expecting only news id.

Comment: I meant that on my second solution (the one with CTE). You are right, it would fail on the first solution

Answer (score 2):

A `group by` is another approach to this:

```
select n.id, n.title, n.description, max(nt.created_at)
      from news n, newstype nt, type t where
      n.id = nt.news_id and
      t.id = nt.type_id
      group by n.id, n.title, n.description
      order by nt.created_at
      limit 25
```

Comment: HA! Tried this on a problem I had the other day and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select distinct n.id, n.title, n.description
```

but, as @Jan Dvorak stated,

```
select distinct n.*
```

shouldn't select the same news twice

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all of the stories that have an entry in the NewsType table for a praticular type. Therefore you want to select the news items where a relationship to the type exists:

```
SELECT
    News.ID,
    News.Title,
    News.Description
FROM
    News
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        NewsType
        INNER JOIN Type ON NewsType.Type_ID = Type.ID
    WHERE
        News.ID = NewsType.News_ID
    AND Type.Type_Code = @typeCode)
```

The last line of the where clause may need to be changed to Type.Type_Name = @typeName if you are using the type name as the parameter

Comment: IMHO, a `where exists` query is too complex for this simple request

Comment: @Teejay you are probably right but it's this scenario that `EXISTS` was designed for. Even if the asker doesn't need it now he is likely to need it when a more complex situation comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what to do with the "duplicate" types: Do you want to display just one type for a news item associated with multiple types, or do you want to list them all?

If the latter, you could investigate using the string_agg function, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html

```
select distinct n.id, n.title, n.description, string_agg(t.type_name, ',')
from news n, newstype nt, type t where
n.id = nt.news_id and
t.id = nt.type_id
group by n.id, n.title, n.description
limit 25
```